# Elasticsearch-OSS 7.9.2 with SSL

Tags: elasticsearch

Can we have an OSS instance of elasticsearch with SSL/https?
I tried [this solution](https://www.elastic.co/blog/configuring-ssl-tls-and-https-to-secure-elasticsearch-kibana-beats-and-logstash), but likely we will need an x-pack that is not available in OSS.

The idea is to have just SSL working in HTTPS, no Authentication required (for testing HTTPS client purposes only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security features in elasticseach are not included in the OSS version, only in the versions that uses at least the Basic free [Elastic License](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions).

To use HTTPS in the OSS version you will need to have a proxy in front of your nodes, like HAProxy and NGINX.